# Gas sensor parameters

Tags: gas-sensor

[image: Gas sensor]
I've just found this sensor on Aliexpress, but the vendor says that he provides more information after the device is bought. There is no information on what sensors does this device feature. I can't even find a manufacturer of this device.

Can anybody provide a datasheet or something?

Comment: If the vendor will not provide detailed specifications **before** purchase then I would strongly suggest that you look for a different vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other vendors that sell similar devices that do provide better information, including output options (voltage or current). Buy **only** from a vendor that supplies the required information, and do not allow copycat vendors to parasitically suck sales away from those who are responsible.

The manufacturer brand is listed as Zhipu, but probably made by a company in Shandong province.